# Change tmux qhortcuts so it to behave like iTerm2

Tags: configuration, shortcuts, tmux

I'm switching from MacOS to Ubuntu. I start pimping everything.

Regarding the terminal, I stick with the default one, but I'm using Tilda on top of it (wonderful!) and now tmux in order to be able to split, resize and so on...

Yet I find tmux too geeky and not user-friendly enough.

Particulary I'm looking for those behavior:

- Ctrl + D to split verticaly
- Ctrl + Shift + D to split horizontally
- Ctrl + Shift + Enter to make the pane fullscreen, and Ctrl + Shift + Enter again to come back to normal view.
- Ctrl + Shift + I to be able to edit every panes simultaneously
- Ctrl + W to kill a window
- Ctrl + Left to swith to the left pane
- Ctrl + Right to swith to the right pane
- Ctrl + Up to swith to the upper pane
- Ctrl + Bottom to switch to the lower pane

I'd also like to be able to resize the pane precisely with the mouse. By default it can only halves it.

That's my wishlist at the moment. I'll be working on it and sharing my .tmux.conf file here by editing this topic until I got this wishlist complete.

Feel free to help (I need a little bit to get on track x) ).

Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure you follow the question and answer format this site requires. Read https://askubuntu.com/help/asking and other sections of the help center.

Comment: `tmux` has a *very* extensive `man` page [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/tmux.1.html) and the `tmux` project has a wiki [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki). Additionally, check out relevant `tmux` questions which have already been asked and answered. You can see some of those in the "Related" area to the right of your screen.